# Battery longevity is less in Ubuntu 20.04 than in Windows

Tags: battery

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10.

My battery lasts for more than 3.30 hours in Windows but in Ubuntu it lasts only 1.30 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Install `tcl` by the following command that can improve your battery performance.

```
sudo apt-get install -y tcl-dev
```

It will automatically start when you turn your PC on.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu, unlike Windows, is a free operating system. And behind Windows, there is a huge amount of commercialism and money.

This means that the drivers for your computer have been optimized for low power consumption, when on Ubuntu this is not the case.

Check out [this omgubuntu article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/improve-battery-life-linux); you should be able to raise the battery life.

Some hints to reduce power consumption:

1. Quit applications you are not using, to free up CPU usage
2. Avoid heavy applications when in battery mode
3. Lower screen brightness; your graphics driver is consuming more resources than Windows graphics drivers because it's not optimized
4. [Install tlp](https://askubuntu.com/a/1255143/527764) - tlp is a powerful tool to help you organize power settings and hardware management.

Cheer up; Ubuntu is vastly more efficient than Windows in all other aspects.